# Is it possible to UPDATE then SELECT in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a column in the table. Set the column to `empty` then execute the select statement.

Right now I am trying to do like below

```
UPDATE issue_meters 
   SET remarks = '' 
   ( SELECT ps.name 'Store name'
                        , im.meter_serial 'Meter Serial Number' 
                        , u.username Issuer 
                        , im.remarks Remarks 
                     FROM issue_meters im
                     JOIN project_store ps 
                       ON im.store_id = ps.id
                     JOIN user u 
                       ON im.issuer = u.id
                 )
```

It's giving me below error

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(select ps.`name` as 'Store name',
>   im.`meter_serial` as 'Meter Serial Number' , ' at line 1

I want to do it in the same query.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: No you cannot do this in one statement.Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to achieve someone may be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Why not just use two queries? There's no association between the two queries.

Comment: @Strawberry, you seem to have fundamentally changed the query, the column is not being set to empty any more. And you have removed the invalid parts. Maybe leave the OP's code as it is?

Comment: _“I want to do it in the same query”_ - then at least give us an explanation as to _why_ you want that. (So that we know what we’re fighting against in explaining to you why that’s nonsense ...)

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually I am generating `PDF` in which I am displaying a remarks column. The column is in my table with `Null` values in it. But when i try to view/download my `pdf` then its showing me as `(not set)` in the column. But i want to be empty. So that's why I want to run Update and Select at same time.

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB doenst support returning select on update.. PostgreSQL on the other hand has.. `UPDATE .... RETURNING [select statement]` (read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)  see http://rextester.com/ONKZ68752

Comment: @Martin Yes I know, and i have done it the same but somehow for any reason it's not working

Comment: I suspect you just need to ditch the update and change the select to include a null test on remarks - eg ifnull(remarks,'')

Comment: @P.Salmon  put `ifnull(remarks, '')` before select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you only need to test for null in your query without updating the base

```
SELECT ps.name 'Store name'
                            , im.meter_serial 'Meter Serial Number' 
                            , u.username Issuer 
                            , ifnull(im.remarks,'') Remarks 
                         FROM issue_meters im
                         JOIN project_store ps 
                           ON im.store_id = ps.id
                         JOIN user u 
                           ON im.issuer = u.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use semicolon between queries:

```
UPDATE `issue_meters` SET `remarks` = '';
SELECT ps.`name` AS 'Store name', 
       im.`meter_serial` AS 'Meter Serial Number' , 
       u.`username` AS 'Issuer' , 
       im.`remarks` AS 'Remarks' 
FROM `issue_meters` im 
INNER JOIN `project_store` ps ON im.`store_id` = ps.`id` 
INNER JOIN `user` u ON im.`issuer` = u.`id`
```

Comment: It's working on my `DB` interface but not in my code

Comment: You can use transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform your command with a single query
 You must use two sql command

```
  UPDATE issue_meters 
   SET remarks = '' ;
```

and you should not use single quote for column name alias  but you need  backtics for column name alias with space  or reserved  word

```
   SELECT ps.name `Store name`
          , im.meter_serial  `Meter Serial Number`
          , u.username Issuer 
        , im.remarks Remarks 
  FROM issue_meters im
  JOIN project_store ps  ON im.store_id = ps.id
  JOIN user u  ON im.issuer = u.id
  ;
```